# Get all related Django model objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, merge

How can I get a list of all the model objects that have a ForeignKey pointing to an object?  (Something like the delete confirmation page in the Django admin before DELETE CASCADE).

I'm trying to come up with a generic way of merging duplicate objects in the database.  Basically I want all of the objects that have ForeignKeys points to object "B" to be updated to point to object "A" so I can then delete "B" without losing anything important.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This [Django snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2283/) is definitely worth checking out!

Comment: I'm trying to implement the exact same thing myself. Would you be willing to share your solution? especailly how did `set` the related object to point to the A ?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

### Django <= 1.7

This gives you the property names for all related objects:

```
links = [rel.get_accessor_name() for rel in a._meta.get_all_related_objects()]
```

You can then use something like this to get all related objects:

```
for link in links:
    objects = getattr(a, link).all()
    for object in objects:
        # do something with related object instance
```

I spent a while trying to figure this out so I could implement a kind of "Observer Pattern" on
one of my models. Hope it's helpful.

### Django 1.8+

Use `_meta.get_fields()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields (see reverse in the `_get_fields()` source also)

Comment: The `all()` part will fail on a `OneToOneField`. You have to detect it somehow.

Comment: It doesn't show ManyToMany connections and was deprecated. In Django 1.8+ it's recommended to be replaced with `_meta.get_fields()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields (see `reverse` in the `_get_fields()` source also)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @int_ua! I'm surprised this workaround remained compatible with Django as long as it did.

Comment: Following on the `_meta.get_fields()` tip, this was part of the solution for me: `links = [field.get_accessor_name() for field in obj._meta.get_fields() if issubclass(type(field), ForeignObjectRel)]` (given `from django.db.models.fields.related import ForeignObjectRel`)

Answer (score 28):

@digitalPBK was close... here is probably what you are looking for using Django's built-in stuff that is used in Django admin for displaying related objects during deletion

```
from django.contrib.admin.utils import NestedObjects
collector = NestedObjects(using="default") #database name
collector.collect([objective]) #list of objects. single one won't do
print(collector.data)
```

this allows you to create what the Django admin displays - the related objects to be deleted.

Comment: FWICT this doesn't work quite correctly. It appears to follow relationships that do not imply the deletion criteria, though I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 9):

`links = [rel.get_accessor_name() for rel in a._meta.get_all_related_objects()]`

You can then use something like this to get all related objects:

```
for link in links:
    objects = getattr(a, link.name).all()
    for object in objects:
        # do something with related object instance
```

From Django 1.10 offical docs:

> MyModel._meta.get_all_related_objects() becomes:

```
[
    f for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields()
    if (f.one_to_many or f.one_to_one)
    and f.auto_created and not f.concrete
]
```

So by taking the approved example we would use:

```
links = [
            f for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields()
            if (f.one_to_many or f.one_to_one)
            and f.auto_created and not f.concrete
        ]

for link in links:
    objects = getattr(a, link.name).all()
    for object in objects:
        # do something with related object instance
```

Comment: Just to correct your answer a little bit

```python
for link in links:
    objects = getattr(a, link.name).all()
    for object in objects:
```

Answer (score 7):

Give this a try.

```
class A(models.Model):
    def get_foreign_fields(self):
      return [getattr(self, f.name) for f in self._meta.fields if type(f) == models.fields.related.ForeignKey]
```

Comment: Don't forget about ManyToMany too

Answer (score 7):

The following is what django uses to get all related objects

```
from django.db.models.deletion import Collector
collector = Collector(using="default")
collector.collect([a])

print collector.data
```

Comment: doesn't seem to cascade. haven't done enough testing around this particluar one to know the full differences, but see my answer for the cascading one.

Answer (score 6):

**Django 1.9**
**get_all_related_objects() has been deprecated**

```
#Example: 
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
print(user._meta.get_fields())
```

Note:
*RemovedInDjango110Warning: 'get_all_related_objects is an unofficial API that has been deprecated. You may be able to replace it with 'get_fields()'*

Comment: get_fields doesn't return related objects.

Comment: It does return reverse connections, even on Django 1.8, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/db/models/options/#Options.get_fields

Answer (score 5):

```
for link in links:
    objects = getattr(a, link).all()
```

Works for related sets, but not for ForeignKeys. Since RelatedManagers are created dynamically, looking at the class name is easier than doing an isinstance()

```
objOrMgr = getattr(a, link)
 if objOrMgr.__class__.__name__ ==  'RelatedManager':
      objects = objOrMgr.all()
 else:
      objects = [ objOrMgr ]
 for object in objects:
      # Do Stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, user._meta.get_fields() returns only relations accessible from user, however, you may have some related object, which uses related_name='+'. In such case, the relation would not be returned by user._meta.get_fields(). Therefore, if You need generic and robust way to merge objects, I'd suggest to use the Collector mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get a list of fields (names only) in related models.

```
def get_related_model_fields(model):
    fields=[]
    related_models = model._meta.get_all_related_objects()
    for r in related_models:
        fields.extend(r.opts.get_all_field_names())
    return fields
```