# Django: How can I find which of my models refer to a model

Tags: django

I'd like to warn or prevent a user from deleting an object instance which is referred to by other instances.  Is there a nice way to do this?

One way would be to get a list of models which include the referent and then try reverse look-ups on them.  Is there a way to get that list of models?  Or is there a better way?

While investigating the collector suggestion, I found some related information and wrote the following which finds the classes which have the referent as a foreign key:

```
def find_related(cl, app):
    """Find all classes which are related to the class cl (in app) by 
    having it as a foreign key."""

    from django.db import models

    all_models = models.get_models()
    ci_model = models.get_model(app, cl)
    for a_model in all_models:
        for f in a_model._meta.fields:
            if isinstance(f, ForeignKey) and (f.rel.to == ci_model):
                print a_model.__name__
```

Based on suggestion to use the code in collect:

```
def find_related(instance):
"""Find all objects which are related to instance."""

for related in instance._meta.get_all_related_objects():
    acc_name = related.get_accessor_name()
    referers = getattr(instance, acc_name).all()
    if referers:
        print related
```

Comment: Thanks for updating this question with your final solution. Excellent work.

Comment: You have `find_related` taking `(cl, app)`, while `get_model` takes `(app, cl)`. It's really confusing! Also, if anyone else is reading this, `cl` and `app` are strings - don't pass the objects!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django has something called [Collector](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/deletion.py#L54) class. It is used by Django when performing a model deletion. What it does seems like exactly what you want. By calling `collect()` it finds all the references to the object in the model graph. Additionally it offers a way to delete all the found objects, with a `delete()` call.

That said I've never used this class myself, I just know it exists. The API is somewhat convoluted, but if you're willing to dig into the internals of Django a little bit, it might save you a lot of coding.

Comment: That does look promising but I'm using 1.0 which only has the predecessor of Collector - CollectedObjects which doesn't look like it has a similar method. CollectedObjects is used in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437166/duplicating-model-instances-and-their-related-objects-in-django-algorithm-for-r) to find objects referred to by the instance to be deleted.

Comment: Can we assume that (a) there is a good reason you can't upgrade to a more recent version and (b) likewise you can't just use the collector on its own?

Comment: @Mitch: Yea, I'd agree with Marcin here, that if you can't upgrade you can always make an attempt to use `Collector.collect()` implementation as a base for your own code. Django code in general is far from clean, but after some analysis, it should be still usable.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at collect and only needed to use a small part to do what I wanted. Another reference is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233883/get-all-related-django-model-objects