# get reverse related models / objects

Tags: django

How do i get the models / objects that relate to a model / object?

I know that a ForeignKey adds accessors. It would be enough to list them.

I have the usual ForeignKey Field szenario:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
   ...
   person = ForeignKey(Person)

class Person(models.Model):
   ...
```

I know i could write person_object.tag_set - the accessor added by the ForeignKey. But that's no option in a generic szenario.

It seems that the class [ForeignObject](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L1302) offers a solution, but how do i use it?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2315053/2395796) to a similar question should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use related_name to get the reverse relation.

> ```
> class Tag(models.Model):
>    ...
>    person = ForeignKey(Person, related_name="tags")
>
> class Person(models.Model):
>    ...
> ```
>
> Person.objects.all()[0].tags.all()