# Get all related model class in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to get a list of all related model class instance that have a Foreign Key relationship, so that I can do something like `model._meta.fields`..

Here is what I have so far:

```
for related_object in A._meta.get_all_related_objects():
        related_name = related_object.field.rel.related_name
```

but I am not sure how to get related model class..

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.model` to get the class name

```
for related_object in A._meta.get_all_related_objects():
    print related_object.model
```

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2233883/1904584) question/answers could be useful for you as well.

Comment: The question was about "get all related model class". This solution returns the instances. Imagine that the tables are empty. This would return no instance. But the related classes exist.

Comment: Previous comment is confusing. This returns a class, but it returns the wrong class, since `model` will return the current class, whereas `related_model` returns what was asked for (the related model, obviously).

Answer (score 4):

In the last Django version (1.8), the options object has a property named related_objects; it will return an iterable with all the foreign relations definitions to the model in place. Each such relation can be inspected for properties:

```python
for relation in A._meta.related_objects:
    print(relation.related_model)    # model which has foreign keys to A
    print(relation.field.name)       # name of the foreign key field
```

The iterable related_objects represents the "reverse" relations (ManyToOneRel, ManyToManyRel) to the A model.

If it's not obvious, is driven by the field definitions rather then the model definitions, meaning that a related model will have as many entries as ForeingKey fields to the A model it has.

Comment: Note: This appears to only return the models that have a foreign key to model A.  It does not appear to also return the models that model A has a foreign key to.

Comment: It also does not appear to return M2M through models unless they are explicit.

Answer (score 2):

This is working in Django version 3.2. You can check it for other versions.

```
for t in A._meta._relation_tree:
    print(t.model)
```

Comment: This works.. Great... Can you help me on how to get related objects per each model given an instance of A

Comment: @Dante ask your question in a separate thread or you can search if it already asked by someone else.

Comment: This appears to only return the models that have a foreign key to model A. It does not appear to also return the models that model A has a foreign key to.  However, unlike Roba's answer, it does return M2M through models even if they aren't explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all related models, including models that have a foreign key to A, and models that A has a foreign key to, you can do this:

```
[field.related_model for field in A._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True) if hasattr(field, 'related_model') and field.related_model]
```