# How can I export an instance and all its related objects in Django?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models

Someone accidentally deleted an instance and all the related objects (through the Django admin) in production. I have a backup of the database, so I can get those data back, but I would like to do it with a script rather than copy the data manually, since it includes *a lot* of related objects.

I would like to retrieve the item that has been deleted (I do have its model and its pk, so I can do `MyModel.objects.get(pk=123456)`), but also all its related objects (`ForeignKey`, `ManyToMany`...) in a way to re-import them in the production database.

It can be either in SQL or any serialized format, to use `loaddata`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To achieve that, you need to combine the [collection of related objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19389817/1433392) and [their serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/serialization/). Since you know the exact model instance that have been deleted, you can first get all the objects deleted (the same way that the django admin does, with a `NestedObjects` collector) and then iterating on this list to generate a json.

The more appropriate is to do a one-time script (note Sept 2016: updated for Django >= 1.9):

```
from itertools import chain      

from django.core import serializers
from django.contrib.admin.utils import NestedObjects

from myproject.myapp.models import MyModel

collector = NestedObjects(using="default") # database name
collector.collect([MyModel.objects.get(pk=123456)])

objects = list(chain.from_iterable(collector.data.values()))
with open("backup_export.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(serializers.serialize("json", objects))
```

This will produce a json file with all the instances that have been deleted. You can now use `manage.py loaddata` to put them back on your production database. When re-importing the json, you [should deactivate the `post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata), otherwise it can failed sometimes with complex dependencies.