# Django, cascading move to a separate table instead of cascading delete

Tags: django, database, soft-delete

I'd like to keep data when we `delete`

instead of `soft-delete` (which uses is_deleted field), I'd like to move the data to another table (for deleted rows)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26125927/433570

I don't know what is the name of the strategy either. called archiving? two-table delete?

To make this work,

I need to be able to do

1. for a given object(which will be deleted), find all other objects that has foreign key or one-to-one key to the object. (this can be done via https://stackoverflow.com/a/2315053/433570, actually harder than that, that code isn't sufficient)
2. insert a new object and have all the objects found in #1 to point to this new object
3. delete the object

(essentiall I'm doing cascading move instead of cascading delete, 1~3 step should be done in recursive fashion)

It would be most convenient to make a mixin for this that supports `delete()` and `undelete()` for a object and for a queryset.

Has anyone created one like this?

Comment: I edited the question, so how do I make this get out of `put-on-hold` status?

Comment: hello, please reopen this :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I implemented this myself and I'm sharing my findings.

#### Archive

First archiving is rather easy since I relaxed foreignkey constraints on archive tables.

You can't keep all constraints in the archive world as you would have in the live world, because what your to-be-deleted object is refering to won't be in the archive world. (because it won't be deleted)

This can be done via mixin (systematically)

Basically, you create archive objects with cascade then delete the original.

#### Unarchive

On the other hand, unarchiving is harder, because you need to confirm to the foreign key constraints.
This can't be done systematically.

It's the same reason why serializers such as Django rest framework won't create related objects magically. You have to know the object graph and constraints.

So that's why there's no library or mixin out there to support this.

Anyway, I'm sharing my mixin code below.

```
 class DeleteModelQuerySet(object):
     '''
     take a look at django.db.models.deletion
     '''

     def hard_delete(self):
         super().delete()

     def delete(self):
         if not self.is_archivable():
             super().delete()
             return

         archive_object_ids = []
         seen = []

         collector = NestedObjects(using='default')  # or specific database
         collector.collect(list(self))
         collector.sort()

         with transaction.atomic():

             for model, instances in six.iteritems(collector.data):

                 if model in self.model.exclude_models_from_archive():
                     continue

                 assert hasattr(model, "is_archivable"), {
                     "model {} doesn't know about archive".format(model)
                 }

                 if not model.is_archivable():
                     # just delete
                     continue

                 for instance in instances:

                     if instance in seen:
                         continue
                     seen.append(instance)

                     for ptr in six.itervalues(instance._meta.parents):
                         # add parents to seen
                         if ptr:
                             seen.append(getattr(instance, ptr.name))

                     archive_object = model.create_archive_object(instance)
                     archive_object_ids.append(archive_object.id)

             # real delete
             super().delete()

         archive_objects = self.model.get_archive_model().objects.filter(id__in=archive_object_ids)
         return archive_objects

     def undelete(self):

         with transaction.atomic():
             self.unarchive()

             super().delete()

     def is_archivable(self):
         # if false, we hard delete instead of archive
         return self.model.is_archivable()

     def unarchive(self):

         for obj_archive in self:
             self.model.create_live_object(obj_archive)


 class DeleteModelMixin(models.Model):

     @classmethod
     def is_archivable(cls):
         # override if you don't want to archive and just delete
         return True

     def get_deletable_objects(self):
         collector = NestedObjects(using='default')  # or specific database
         collector.collect(list(self))
         collector.sort()
         deletable_data = collector.data

         return deletable_data

     @classmethod
     def create_archive_object(cls, obj):
         # http://stackoverflow.com/q/21925671/433570
         # d = cls.objects.filter(id=obj.id).values()[0]

         d = obj.__dict__.copy()
         remove_fields = []
         for field_name, value in six.iteritems(d):
             try:
                 obj._meta.get_field(field_name)
             except FieldDoesNotExist:
                 remove_fields.append(field_name)
         for remove_field in remove_fields:
             d.pop(remove_field)

         cls.convert_to_archive_dictionary(d)

         # print(d)

         archive_object = cls.get_archive_model().objects.create(**d)
         return archive_object

     @classmethod
     def create_live_object(cls, obj):

         # index error, dont know why..
         # d = cls.objects.filter(id=obj.id).values()[0]

         d = obj.__dict__.copy()

         remove_fields = [cls.convert_to_archive_field_name(field_name) + '_id' for field_name in cls.get_twostep_field_names()]
         for field_name, value in six.iteritems(d):
             try:
                 obj._meta.get_field(field_name)
             except FieldDoesNotExist:
                 remove_fields.append(field_name)

         for remove_field in remove_fields:
             d.pop(remove_field)

         cls.convert_to_live_dictionary(d)

         live_object = cls.get_live_model().objects.create(**d)
         return live_object

     @classmethod
     def get_archive_model_name(cls):
         return '{}Archive'.format(cls._meta.model_name)

     @classmethod
     def get_live_model_name(cls):

         if cls._meta.model_name.endswith("archive"):
             length = len("Archive")
             return cls._meta.model_name[:-length]
         return cls._meta.model_name

     @classmethod
     def get_archive_model(cls):
         # http://stackoverflow.com/a/26126935/433570
         return apps.get_model(app_label=cls._meta.app_label, model_name=cls.get_archive_model_name())

     @classmethod
     def get_live_model(cls):
         return apps.get_model(app_label=cls._meta.app_label, model_name=cls.get_live_model_name())

     @classmethod
     def is_archive_model(cls):
         if cls._meta.model_name.endswith("Archive"):
             return True
         return False

     @classmethod
     def is_live_model(cls):
         if cls.is_archive_model():
             return False
         return True

     def make_referers_point_to_archive(self, archive_object, seen):

         instance = self

         for related in get_candidate_relations_to_delete(instance._meta):
             accessor_name = related.get_accessor_name()

             if accessor_name.endswith('+') or accessor_name.lower().endswith("archive"):
                 continue

             referers = None

             if related.one_to_one:
                 referer = getattr(instance, accessor_name, None)
                 if referer:
                     referers = type(referer).objects.filter(id=referer.id)
             else:
                 referers = getattr(instance, accessor_name).all()

             refering_field_name = '{}_archive'.format(related.field.name)

             if referers:
                 assert hasattr(referers, 'is_archivable'), {
                     "referers is not archivable: {referer_cls}".format(
                         referer_cls=referers.model
                     )
                 }

                 archive_referers = referers.delete(seen=seen)
                 if referers.is_archivable():
                     archive_referers.update(**{refering_field_name: archive_object})

     def hard_delete(self):
         super().delete()

     def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self._meta.model.objects.filter(id=self.id).delete()

     def undelete(self, commit=True):
         self._meta.model.objects.filter(id=self.id).undelete()

     def unarchive(self, commit=True):
         self._meta.model.objects.filter(id=self.id).unarchive()

     @classmethod
     def get_archive_field_names(cls):
         raise NotImplementedError('get_archive_field_names() must be implemented')

     @classmethod
     def convert_to_archive_dictionary(cls, d):

         field_names = cls.get_archive_field_names()
         for field_name in field_names:
             field_name = '{}_id'.format(field_name)
             archive_field_name = cls.convert_to_archive_field_name(field_name)
             d[archive_field_name] = d.pop(field_name)

     @classmethod
     def convert_to_live_dictionary(cls, d):

         field_names = list(set(cls.get_archive_field_names()) - set(cls.get_twostep_field_names()))

         for field_name in field_names:
             field_name = '{}_id'.format(field_name)
             archive_field_name = cls.convert_to_archive_field_name(field_name)
             d[field_name] = d.pop(archive_field_name)

     @classmethod
     def convert_to_archive_field_name(cls, field_name):
         if field_name.endswith('_id'):
             length = len('_id')
             return '{}_archive_id'.format(field_name[:-length])
         return '{}_archive'.format(field_name)

     @classmethod
     def convert_to_live_field_name(cls, field_name):
         if field_name.endswith('_archive_id'):
             length = len('_archive_id')
             return '{}_id'.format(field_name[:-length])
         if field_name.endswith('archive'):
             length = len('_archive')
             return '{}'.format(field_name[:-length])
         return None

     @classmethod
     def get_twostep_field_names(cls):
         return []

     @classmethod
     def exclude_models_from_archive(cls):
         # excluded model can be deleted if referencing to me
         # or just lives if I reference him
         return []

     class Meta:
         abstract = True
```

Comment: I made a Gist of this code and added the missing imports: https://gist.github.com/adamlwgriffiths/4fb6a47bb84ec6e34424

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for any 3rd party django-package for specific service or functionality, you can always search in [www.djangopackages.com](https://www.djangopackages.com) if you don't have any idea about the existing one. It will provide you also with a comparison table between the package to help you make the right choice.
Based on the [table here](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/deletion/): **django-reversion** is the most used, have stable version, active community in github and last update is 3 days ago, which means the project is very well maintained and reliable.

To install **django-reversion**, follow these steps:

1.Install with pip: `pip install django-reversion`.

2.Add 'reversion' to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

3.Run `manage.py migrate`

Check [here](http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for more details and configuration

Comment: I meant `soft-delete` to mean a methodology of using `is_delete`. I edited the op. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I looked at django-reversion, I don't think it supports `delete-undelete`

Comment: These appear to all use a `deleted_on` field, rather than moving models to a different table.