# Django NestedObjects like in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, django-models, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In the stackoverflow below is mention how to fetch all related objects in Django

[Get all related Django model objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233883/get-all-related-django-model-objects/)

To be short, the solution that best fits my needs would be something like code below..

```py
from django.contrib.admin.utils import NestedObjects
collector = NestedObjects(using="default") #database name
collector.collect([objective]) #list of objects. single one won't do
print(collector.data)
```

Basically I'm trying to figure out how to do the same approach but using SqlAlchemy.

Thanks in advance!!